# Nonlinear semi group

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Good Morning,

I search for a theorem in the theory of a nonlinear semigroup, which gives the global existence of a solution of a PDE, with some regularity of course.

Are there any recommended references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two references which help me a lot:

Barbu Viorel. - Nonlinear semigroups and differential equations in Banach spaces.

Nonlinear semi-groups in Hilbert space by Yukio Komura.